# Rails API- Can't convert Symbol into Integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

I am getting this error when processing a api test on my rails app.

The error is;

```
can't convert Symbol into Integer

app/controllers/api/v1/xml/messages_controller.rb:5:in `[]='
app/controllers/api/v1/xml/messages_controller.rb:5:in `create'
```

and

```
{"username"=>"info@skylinesms.com",
 "password"=>"[FILTERED]",
 "to"=>"256776582036",
 "from"=>"acacia",
 "message"=>"hello acacia",
 "format"=>:xml}
```

And i suspect the problem is the `"format" => :xml` in parameters. How di i stop it from being passed in?

The controller is:

```
    def create
    @user = current_user
    @message = Message.new(params[:message])
    @message.user_id = current_user.id
    @message.status = 'Queued'
    if @message.save
        MessageWorker.perform_async(@message.id, lists, current_user.id)
        render json: {status: "success", to: @message.count, from: @message.from, 
                      balance: @user.balance, message: @message.message, 
                      time: @message.created_at} 
    else
        render status: 400 
    end
end
```

line 5 is

`@message = Message.new(params[:message])`

The backtrace is

```
app/controllers/api/v1/xml/messages_controller.rb:5:in `create'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:414:in `_run__645129932408314116__process_action__3356705148777596390__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:207:in `process_action'
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
newrelic_rpm (3.6.7.159) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/rails3/action_controller.rb:38:in `block in process_action'
newrelic_rpm (3.6.7.159) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/controller_instrumentation.rb:324:in `perform_action_with_newrelic_trace'
newrelic_rpm (3.6.7.159) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/rails3/action_controller.rb:37:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:612:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.6.7.159) lib/new_relic/rack/error_collector.rb:43:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.6.7.159) lib/new_relic/rack/agent_hooks.rb:22:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.6.7.159) lib/new_relic/rack/browser_monitoring.rb:16:in `call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:210:in `context'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:341:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__3057558528737021071__call__666448881149873332__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:136:in `forward'
rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:143:in `pass'
rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:155:in `invalidate'
rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:71:in `call!'
rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in `call'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
passenger (4.0.8) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb:77:in `process_request'
passenger (4.0.8) lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:140:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
passenger (4.0.8) lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:108:in `main_loop'
passenger (4.0.8) lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:441:in `block (3 levels) in start_threads'
```

made a quick fix like this

```
    def create
    @user = current_user
    @message = Message.new(params[:message])
    @message.message = params[:message][:text]
    @message.user_id = current_user.id
    @message.status = 'Queued'
    if @message.save
        MessageWorker.perform_async(@message.id, lists, current_user.id)
        render json: {status: "success", to: @message.count, from: @message.from, 
                      balance: @user.balance, message: @message.message, 
                      time: @message.created_at} 
    else
        render status: 400 
    end
end
```

and now getting this error

```
undefined method `[]=' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: what is line number 5 in your controller ? Isn't it a before_filter or something ?

Comment: @OlivierElMekki i have edited, check the bottom!

Comment: What is the source of `Message` class?

Comment: @MarekLipka, what do u mean by source? this the class definition `class Api::V1::Json::MessagesController < ApplicationController`

Comment: No, I mean `Message`, not `MessagesController`.

Comment: @MarekLipka, message is a model that is used by other controllers `class Message < ActiveRecord::Base` and `attr_accessible :message, :phone, :status, :to, :from, :user_id`

Comment: Paste full error backtrace. And please, paste it in your question, not in comments.

Comment: @MarekLipka  please look at the edit

Answer (score 2):

You can't create a Message when instead of the hash, you pass a string.

Your `params[:message]` call returns `'hello acacia'` so on line 5 you actually call:

```
 @message = Message.new('hello acacia')
```

which is invalid.

Message is an ActiveRecord::Model so its initializer expects a hash.

Comment: How can i be able to pass message value in a message hash?

Comment: In which attribute of your Message model do you store the message? If for example your message model has an attribute `content` then you should something like this: `@message = Message.new(content: params[:message])`

Comment: its is stored in message

Comment: Can you post your Message's class source?

Comment: I don't see the Message class source in your post.

Comment: i found a way around that with quick fix added. I am asking about the new error!

Comment: I don't think your quick fix is valid. You are not following the proper way on initializing your model.

Comment: Ok, could you post the source of your message.rb file in order to point out what you should do?